# How to handle UnexpectedRollbackException?

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting `UnexpectedRollbackException` in my spring application. Here is my Repository class

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public MyData save(MyData myData){
        return em.merge(myData)
    }
}
```

Here is my Service class

```
@Service
public class MyService{
    @Autowired
    Mydao myDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveMyData(MyData myData){
        myDao.save(myData);
    }
}
```

Here I'm calling the service method.

```
@Component
public class ScheduledService{

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=60000)
    public void myDataScheduler(){
        // ... create mydata object
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            myService.saveMyData(myData);
    }
}
```

MyData has some constraints so I'm expecting `ConstraintViolationException`. All I need to do is, if `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown, fail silently. As there is no other DB operation inside the service method, I guess I don't need rollback here. But I'm getting the following exception when a constraint violates. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
2015-08-24 18:01:28,677 SEVERE [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-5-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1024) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.myapp.service.saveMyData() [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.commit(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:173)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1021) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1882) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:358)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:114) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (IM.UK_K4P6Q9JG3ANIQKAWWAI65TWX5) violated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: i guess you you already have a entry for the unique constraint and trying to save another one raises a `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` and since your service method as the `@Transactional` annotation it  raises other exceptions which are `UnexpectedRollbackException` and `RollBackException`. If you want to only have the `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` remove the `@Transactional` annotation but there won't be rollback anymore and that could be very bad.

Comment: FOr starters stop mixing different spring versions... You are currently mixing 4.0.7 and 4.1.6 that is generally a bad idea. Next you are violating a unique constraint so a field has to be unique and it isn't.

Comment: Your stack trace says `Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (IM.UK_K4P6Q9JG3ANIQKAWWAI65TWX5) violated`, which clearly tells you, that the root cause for the `UnexpectedRollbackException` is the violation of one of your unique constrains. Which is what you expected.

Comment: I've inserted same data already and that's why I'm getting `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException `. But I want to avoid `RollbackException` and `UnexpectedRollbackException`. How can I do this? Please keep in mind that I'm very new in spring

Comment: @Rafiqunnabi First you should solve your `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` and then you can remove the `@Transactional`  but **only** if you have some data integrity check elsewhere.

Comment: @Deh Can you please suggest how to solve `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`? My plan was to let `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ` be thrown so that I can detect unique constraint violation and fail silently. Should I do it in any other way?

Comment: @Rafiqunnabi the trouble is not in the Exception raised it's in the data you want to save, you're trying to save data that already exists and that's what cause the  `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. so correct the data and the exception won't raise.

Comment: "My plan was to let SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException be thrown so that I can detect unique constraint violation and fail silently" This is a very bad plan. If you have a problem with your database entries, then fix that. If you have duplicate entries, then find out, why you try to store another version of them.

Comment: In my situation, I'm crawling some data periodically from an external API and storing it into my DB. If any data already exists in my DB, that means I've already stored it hence I want to ignore it. I've an option to query for that data before insertion but I didn't do it as it requires two DB operations.

Comment: And what do you think will happen if you persist a load of data in an transaction and one of them is a duplicate? .... I hope you're using transactions ...

Comment: @Tom I understand the issue. Thanks a lot for your time. I'm going to redesign my code so that `ConstraintViolationException` is never going to happen.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't happen and you should try to use transaction for a save rollback if something went wrong. Good luck with the refactoring :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've designed the flow was a very bad one indeed.

I've redesigned the flow. Before trying to insert the object in the DB, I'm doing a select query based on the constraints. If the query finds any objects, I'm throwing a custom exception `DataAlreadyExistsException`. Otherwise I'm doing the insertion.

This solved my problem. Thanks to all who helped me in figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

*"All I need to do is, if ConstraintViolationException is thrown, fail silently. As there is no other DB operation inside the service method, I guess I don't need rollback here."*

This is what Spring does not know until you instruct it. What you are experiencing is this:

- you start a transaction
- you execute a DB operation
- your DB operation fails (and you are ok with this)
- As your expected exception (ConstraintViolation) was not actually expected (you did not handle it) it reaches the transaction cutpoint
- at this point Spring assumes that the whole transaction needs to be rolled back.

Hence the UnexpectedRollbackException. **To prevent this, the only thing you need to do is catch** (and swallow, if you really want to ignore this problem) **the original ConstraintViolationException WITHIN the transaction**. Inside the `saveMyData()` for example would be ok.

Comment: Depending on your setup there is a large change that isn't going to work. Hibernate is only going to send the SQL to the server if it really has to. In this case it is already trying to commit the data, leading to flushing the SQL to the database. At that point it is going to fail. Catching the exception inside that method is going to be pretty pointless as the exception is occurring after the method execution.

Comment: As I'm not flushing the data in DAO, cathcing `ConstraintViolationException ` within the transaction will not be useful in this case.